# Como establezco un textbox a solo numeros C#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto con un sistema de gráficos son 4 textboxs que establecerán el tamaño del grafico

```
public Pen pincel = new Pen(Color.White, 1);
        public Graphics Line;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            float sx = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            bool sxv = float.TryParse(textBox1.Text.ToString(), out sx);
            float sy = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            bool syv = float.TryParse(textBox2.Text.ToString(), out sy);
            float ex = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            bool exv = float.TryParse(textBox3.Text.ToString(), out ex);
            float ey = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            bool eyv = float.TryParse(textBox4.Text.ToString(), out ey);



            Line = panelg.CreateGraphics();
            Line.DrawLine(pincel,sx, sy, ex, ey);
        }
```

esto se encarga de limpiar pizarra cuando se clica

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Line.Clear(Color.Black);
        }
```

esto se encarga de crear un elipse cuando se clica
los float y bool son para transformar el string del textbox a float para ser aceptados por el metodo draw

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float sx = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            bool sxv = float.TryParse(textBox1.Text.ToString(), out sx);
            float sy = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            bool syv = float.TryParse(textBox2.Text.ToString(), out sy);
            float ex = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            bool exv = float.TryParse(textBox3.Text.ToString(), out ex);
            float ey = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            bool eyv = float.TryParse(textBox4.Text.ToString(), out ey);

            Line = panelg.CreateGraphics();
            Line.DrawEllipse(pincel, sx, sy, ex, ey);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float sx = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            bool sxv = float.TryParse(textBox1.Text.ToString(), out sx);
            float sy = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            bool syv = float.TryParse(textBox2.Text.ToString(), out sy);
            float ex = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            bool exv = float.TryParse(textBox3.Text.ToString(), out ex);
            float ey = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            bool eyv = float.TryParse(textBox4.Text.ToString(), out ey);

            Line = panelg.CreateGraphics();
            Line.DrawRectangle(pincel, sx, sy, ex, ey);

        }
```

esto es una de las acciones que crea un rectangulo

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Line = panelg.CreateGraphics();
            Line.DrawRectangle(pincel, 45, 45, 45, 45);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string empety = "";
            if (String.Compare(textBox1.Text,empety) == 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "0";
                if (String.Compare(textBox2.Text, empety) == 0)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = "0";
                    if (String.Compare(textBox3.Text, empety) == 0)
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = "0";
                        if (String.Compare(textBox4.Text, empety) == 0)
                        {
                            textBox4.Text = "0";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

en el form_load reviso que el los textbox tengan nada y luego establezco sus valores a 0 los floats y bool son para convertir los string en float
como puedo hacer que solo acepten numeros para que no ande crasheando cada 2x3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crearas un evento para tu botón tipo TextChanged, utilizando expresiones reguales.

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, "^[0-9]*$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Esto es a mi parecer lo más efectivo, otra alternativa es bloquear que puedan teclear letras con un evento KeyPress.

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```